# How to annotate (highlight) text in the PDF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I was wondering about open source project to view and annotate PDFs. I have tried [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), but this one does not provide annotating. I am also open to ideas on how this could be done without any library

What I am looking for:

- Highlight the text and set background colour
- Store this information in the backend
- Display PDF without highlights
- Possibility to show highlighted text in the PDF

Comment: The aim is for the user to collaborate on PDF and highlight the desired text, with perhaps having an option to add a comment to that area. Original PDF should not be modified, thus saving these annotations externally. I am open to ideas, it is more like a research question, to understand how this can be done

Comment: Taking it to a bit different approach, let's consider it as two separate components, where the first one is PDF and the second one is some kind of transparent shape (highlight). Is there some simple way to add this shape on top of PDF as a separate layer only visually in the browser? From your andswer, I understand that modifying actual PDF is a complex process, so I would like to take a different approach. It sounds simple, so I would like to understand the complexity it will bring, and as you mentioned, perhaps consider paying for an already existing solution.

Comment: If I wanted to implement this overlay, let's say on top of the pdf rendered by pdf.js (or any other viewer), where would you suggest starting?